# VSC on OSX - How to open the selected file at VSC Explorer using Keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've used VSC on Windows, Ubuntu and OSX.  In Windows and Ubuntu, I can open the selected file from Explorer(in VSC) by pressing "Enter" key.

However when I press "Enter" key at VSC Explorer in OSX, it just activates "File rename" text box at selected file.

Is there any way to open the selected file using keyboard at VSC Explorer in OSX?

Thanks for your answer in advance!
Jin

Comment: That happens in OSX's regular Finder too. In Finder using Cmd+O is what opens files so you could try that.

Answer (score 3):

On OSX you can open a file by pressing `Cmd+ArrowDown`. This is currently not configurable.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin!  Once I open it, is there any easy way to move focus to Editor?

Comment: You can press Cmd+1 to focus the editor at position 1 and 2 or 3 when you have multiple editors open. To open multiple editors press Cmd+Enter. Though I would assume that Cmd+ArrowDown moves focus to the editor automatically, does it not for you?

Comment: Looks like an issue on our end, I am looking into a fix for the update after the next one!

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I'm looking forward to next version.